# Redirection not working with various methods

Tags: php, html, redirect

I've the following PHP script launching on click of a submit form button :

```
<?php
//header('Location: video_download.html');
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["logo"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$new_name = 'logo'.'.'.$imageFileType;
$target_file = $target_dir . $new_name;
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check == false) {
        echo "File is not an image.\n";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["logo"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.\n";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "png") {
    echo "Sorry, only PNG files are allowed.\n";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.\n";

if (file_exists("config.txt")) {
    unlink("config.txt");
}
if (file_exists("upload/logo.png")) {
    unlink("upload/logo.png");
}
// if everything is ok, try to upload file & create config.txt
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                $template = $_POST['template'] . "\n";
                $club = $_POST['club'] . "\n";
                $stats = $_POST['stats'];
                if (file_exists("config.txt")) {
                    unlink("config.txt");
                }
                file_put_contents("config.txt", $template . $club . $stats);
                echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=video_download.html">';
                shell_exec("./blender_lite/bin/blender -b -P blender.py");
                exit();
        } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading your file.\n";
                exit();
    }
}
?>
```

I want it to redirect the browser to another html page after executing all script's content. I've tried two different approach : the header (commented in the above code) and echoing an html meta tag with a redirection.

Both doesn't work for unknown reasons and I can't find it (already passed many hours trying to find other methods and resolve the issue without success, so I guess it's kind of a specific issue with a part of my php script). Any help is welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the redirection worked fine as I did on my first post. The issue was that PHP waits for the shell_exec to be over. Thus, since I was launching a blender rendering with shell_exec, it was taking several minutes to end so I thought the redirection was not working.

Using `exec('bash -c "exec nohup setsid ./blender_lite/bin/blender -b -P blender.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &"');`

instead of `shell_exec("./blender_lite/bin/blender -b -P blender.py");`

so the PHP script doesn't wait for the command to end is the solution, the redirection is now immediate.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the header function.

```
header("Location: http://www.website.com/page.php");
exit();
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't relevant since with the exit function right after the header, the rest of the script is not executed. Thanks for contributing, if you have a better solution, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the part of your code where you echo the meta refresh with the header location command and place it at the end of your logic. This will only redirect when everything else is complete then.

Example:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["logo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            $template = $_POST['template'] . "\n";
            $club = $_POST['club'] . "\n";
            $stats = $_POST['stats'];
            if (file_exists("config.txt")) {
                unlink("config.txt");
            }
            file_put_contents("config.txt", $template . $club . $stats);
            shell_exec("./blender_lite/bin/blender -b -P blender.py");
            header('Location: video_download.html'); // <-- put redirect here
            exit();
    } else {
    echo "There was an error uploading your file.\n";
            exit();
}
```